# Laggy opacity change in Chrome with large scaled images

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, opacity, lag, fadeto

I have a simple slide show where I fade out the current photo before displaying the new one.
It works great under FF and IE, but effect is very laggy in Chrome...

I spotted that lagginess in Chrome appears only on large scaled images

Here is the code to reproduce :

```
    this.oldimg  = this.img;
    this.img = new Image(); 
    $(this.img).css({width: '90%', height: '90%'});
    $(this.img).attr("src", "//file.jpg");
    $("body").prepend(this.img);
    if(this.oldimg) $(this.oldimg).fadeTo(600, 0, function() { $(this).remove();  });
```

Working demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/f3tta/18/embedded/result/

(Note: Comments were made in reference to a previous demo avoiding browser cache [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f3tta/10/))

Can you reproduce?
What solution do I have to avoid the lagginess without having to serve perfectly scaled images ?

Comment: Seems like the images are loading, as you have effectively removed all caching. See if this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f3tta/11/) solves the problem.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem for the first loop, but it does for the next ones. Anyway, I have a very long list of files and I can't preload them all at start.

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out a way to preload the next image in line before it's changed.

Comment: In fact, it does not even solve the problem for the first loop, but it's kind of random. When i do quick clicks, effect seems to work, but when I pause for a few sec between each clicks, effect doesn't work ! Very strange.

Comment: i already do preloading in my real script, this is not the problem :(

Comment: Okay, so this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3tta/18/embedded/result/) shows the bug with cached images !

Comment: Besides, using CSS3 to do the same thing results in the same behaviour :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so if anybody comes here with the same problem, I found a solution to bypass the issue :

```
if(this.oldimg) $(this.oldimg).delay(50).fadeTo(600, 0, function() { $(this).remove();
```

I don't know why, when we delay the fading out a little, chrome play the effect almost normally.